# Server 2019 Storage Pool (3 columns, 2 copies) - Unexplainable Behaviour

Tags: windows-server-2019, storage-spaces

i've been using storing spaces since many many years now and thought I understood how it works. Recently, i got hands on a decomissioned 24-bay SAN and decided to modify it a bit to be used with my (single-node) hardware.

I have now some strange behaviour of the Storage-Pools I cannot explain - and hence I will start deep down at the layout, cause maybe I already made a thinking misstake *there* which results in the issues i'm seeing.

So, first things first:

- I have 2 good old Adaptec 71605. (4x 6GB SAS-Cards)
- My Server is running purely of SSDs, which can almost exhaust one HBA port on their own.
- So, to get the maximum Performance out of this, I decided to create **4 Storage Pools**, each having 6 SSDs, while each SSD is connected to another HBA-Port. Thus, If one Pool is busy and the others are sleeping, the 6 disks could exclusively use One HBA Port each to get the maximum speed out of it.
- Since I need redundancy, that ofc then comes down to a 3 columns, 2 copies layout which should be somewhere around 1500 MB/s (each SSD does about 500)

This all seems to work well, testing it, I get the expected Performance and disks beeing busy.

***First Issue***

While I was printing some fan holders for the HBAs, I didn't put one back into it's slot correctly. *As Expected* 12 Disks went missing. And As Expected it was now 3 missing disks per Storage-Pool.

However, what was totally unexpected was: Each Pool went offline saying "faulted". It wasn't possible to bring them online.

My original assumption would have been, that if 3 disks of a 3x2 Pool fail, the pool should still be available in a degraded state?

So, my thought here is, that Storage Spaces - even if the data is theoretically healthy - doesn't consider it healthy/degraded, because there is no kind of quorum of disks present anymore. (So, If the pool would spawn multiple encolsures, a split-brain should be avoided?)

***Second Issue***

Last week, I experienced a real disk-failures and this time the pool remained online, but degraded. Cool, that's expected. (So far).

Now, normaly the Disk that failed would be in a **Lost Communication** State, until you add a replacement, set the disk to retired, have data copied over and finally remove it. (Did this multiple times during the past years)

So, I was surprised, that the Disk turned to **Retired** after some time on it's own. Anyway, not paying further attention on that, I added another disk, invoked the rebuild of the virtual disk and removed the Retired disk.

The Issue I am seeing now is that the **new disk** remains at **no usage**. Usage of all other disks about equal - but the virtual Disk reports to be in an healty state, while only utilizing 5 disks.

How is that possible?

I know, that you can repair a virtual disk (or that storage spaces does it automatically) if there are unused disks present in the pool - but the pool only had 6 disks, 1 of them failed - how could it "repair" a 3 column 2 copy disk on 5 disks?

I was out for 6 days, so that's the time I didn't manually repair the pool.

Is it kind of a hidden feature that storage spaces decides that it restores "health" and violates the column-constraint - or did I funamentally missunderstand what 3 columns, 2 disks means?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer for Issue Number 2. Even if it looks weird at first - it absolutely makes sence:

- When you start with a 3 column, 2 copy Pool, it needes 6 disks to be healty. 3 disks to write and 3 disks for each copy.
- When a disk fails, the pool becomes **unhealty**. It now can restore **resiliency** by restoring the missing blocks on other disks.
- The Pool can now **read** from 3 columns again and has a copy of each block - so, from a **Read-Access** Point-of-View, the pool is now healty again. It just can't write to 3*2 disks simultaneously.
- When a new disk is added - the pool immediately is **healty** again, even if the new disk is not used by now, because:
- The  Pool can now **write** to 3 columns / 2 copies again.

Think of this simple data set, made out of 1 data block:

[image]

ps.: With `Optimize-StoragePool` can you can restore the correct column-alignment if desired.

pps.: I've tested it out of curiosity: This ofc. is only possible if the pool has enough **unassigned** capacity left on the remaining disks. If 100% is allocated, restoring health like this won't/can't happen.